# Can't get the TeamCity eclipse plug-in remote run to work

Tags: eclipse, teamcity, perforce

I'm trying to test the Remote Run function with the Eclipse Plugin but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm getting the following error:

There are no build configurations that can be triggered with the selected files. Please check that the following conditions are met:
local VCS settings correspond to the VCS settings of the target build configurations on the TeamCity server;
you have view and run build permissions for the target project.

I've created .teamcity-mappings.properties and put it in the root folder of my project

I'm running on Fedora:

Eclipse Version 4.7.1a
Perforce + Perforce plugin for Eclipse
TeamCity 2017.1.2

I tried running eclipse with the --debug flag and the appropriate teamcity options set to true, and on the console I'm seeing this, where the highlighted file is the change I did and want to build with it:

```
DEBUG_UI     - Task "Preparing for TeamCity Remote Run" started
2018-12-19 09:14:10,217 DEBUG [Worker-8] DEBUG_VCS_DETAIL     - PerforceSyncInfo: "**perforce://perforce:1666:////ProductsTasks2016/annag_from_trunk/1250Base/AppDev/utils/size.sh**" haveRevision=2 headRevision=2
2018-12-19 09:14:10,217 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_VCS     -  TCWorkspaceSubscriber.collectOutOfSync(): Summary for 1 root(s): [1] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:10,218 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_VCS     -  RemoteRunAction.getStatuses: Summary: [2] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:10,218 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_VCS     -    1 SyncInfos collected: [2] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:10,218 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_VCS     -    1 RemoteResource got: [0] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:10,218 DEBUG [Worker-8] DEBUG_TEAMCITY     - Asking Applicable Configurations for 1 resources
2018-12-19 09:14:10,218 DEBUG [Worker-8] DEBUG_VCS_DETAIL     - Asking Applicable Configurations for [perforce://perforce:1666:////ProductsTasks2016/annag_from_trunk/1250Base/AppDev/utils/size.sh]
2018-12-19 09:14:10,278 DEBUG [Worker-8] DEBUG_TEAMCITY     - Asking Applicable Configurations took 60 milliseconds
2018-12-19 09:14:10,279 DEBUG [Worker-8] DEBUG_TEAMCITY     - Asking Applicable Configurations: 0 configurations found
2018-12-19 09:14:10,279 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_TEAMCITY     -  Util.getApplicableConfigurations: Summary: [61] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:10,279 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_TEAMCITY     -       0 found configuration(s): [60] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:10,279 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_TEAMCITY     -       0 checked configuration(s), 0 accepted: [0] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:23,380 DEBUG [Worker-8] DEBUG_VCS_DETAIL     - PerforceSyncInfo: "perforce://perforce:1666:////ProductsTasks2016/annag_from_trunk/1250Base/AppDev/utils/size.sh" haveRevision=2 headRevision=2
2018-12-19 09:14:23,380 DEBUG [Worker-8] PERFORMANCE_VCS     -  PerforceChangeSetManager.resourceChanged(REFRESHED): 1 IP4Changelist(s) processed: [1] ms
2018-12-19 09:14:23,381 DEBUG [Worker-16] DEBUG_VCS_DETAIL     - PerforceSyncInfo: "perforce://perforce:1666:////ProductsTasks2016/annag_from_trunk/1250Base/AppDev/utils/size.sh" haveRevision=2 headRevision=2
2018-12-19 09:14:23,481 DEBUG [Worker-20] DEBUG_VCS_DETAIL     - PerforceSyncInfo: "perforce://perforce:1666:////ProductsTasks2016/annag_from_trunk/1250Base/AppDev/utils/size.sh" haveRevision=2 headRevision=2
2018-12-19 09:14:23,484 DEBUG [Worker-19] DEBUG_VCS_DETAIL     - PerforceSyncInfo: "perforce://perforce:1666:////ProductsTasks2016/annag_from_trunk/1250Base/AppDev/utils/size.sh" haveRevision=2 headRevision=2
```

I tried to remove the .teamcity-mappings.properties file from the root directory of the project. When I press on remote run I receive the same errors, so seems like the file is not reflected for some reason…

The content of the file:

```
utils=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev/utils
u-boot/vrm=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/u-boot-vrm/vrm
u-boot/include/vrm=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/u-boot-vrm/include/vrm
u-boot/common/cmd_update.c=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/u-boot-vrm/common/cmd_update.c
u-boot=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/3800Core/u-boot-3802
samples=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev/samples
makefiles=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev/makefiles
host=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/Host
config/version=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/RiceKrispies_TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev/config/version
config=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev/config
apps=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev/apps
Makefile=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev/Makefile
Core/lwip=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/CorePacks/lwip-2.0.0.RC2
Core/include=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/CorePacks/sysroots/FreeRTOS/include
Core/FreeRTOS=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/CorePacks/RTOS/FreeRTOSV8.2.3/FreeRTOS
Core=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/CorePacks
BuildUtils=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/BuildUtils
1250Base/u-boot-vrm=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/u-boot-vrm
1250Base/AppDev=perforce://perforce:1666:////Products/TRUNK/1250Base/AppDev
```